# How to add the button in uitableviewcell in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am new in ipad development i want to add the button in uitableviewcell but it is not displaying. how to add this button in tableview cell. I am writing this code in cellforRowAtIndexPath My code is:

```
UIButton *cellImgButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 350, 40, 40)];
cellImgButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"remove.png"];
[cellImgButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cellImgButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cellImgButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView  addSubview:cellImgButton];
```

Thanks in Advance:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a prototype cell in interface builder and drag a UIButton in the cell. after that create a new UITableViewCell class and link the button.

*don't forget to add a identifier to the cell*

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your button's frame. Try this :

```
UIButton *cellImgButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[cellImgButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 40 , 40) ];

UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"remove.png"];
[cellImgButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cellImgButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cellImgButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.contentView  addSubview:cellImgButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. You mentioned the 'Y axis' is 350. Please check you row height. And give the 'Y' axis related to your row height.

```
UIButton *cellImgButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[cellImgButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 40 , 40) ];
[cellImgButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"remove.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cellImgButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cellImgButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:cellImgButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

1)check Table cell height

2)Check frame size of button  (means x and y axies)